# Vaccination requirement for entering the US

Tags: usa, covid-19, vaccinations

The US TSA had set (and then extended) a vaccination requirement for non-citizens/LPRs (with a few exceptions) to enter the US until January 8, 2023.  With the 8th only a couple of days away, has this restriction been lifted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you are talking about the vaccination requirement for entry by air, instead of for entry by land. The vaccination requirement for entry to the US by air for nonimmigrants was set by [Presidential Proclamation 10294](https://www.federalregister.gov/d/2021-23645). This proclamation has no end date. Until it is explicitly rescinded by the President, this vaccination requirement will remain in effect.

> Sec. 5. Termination. This proclamation shall remain in effect until terminated by the President.

Comment: Interesting - why then would the TSA keep announcing end-dated restrictions (per my answer)?

Answer (score 3):

On January 4, 2023, the TSA released an update to the requirement, extending the period through until at least **April 10, 2023**.

> NUMBER - EA1546-21-02B
> SUBJECT - Requirements for Proof of Being Fully Vaccinated Against  COVID-19
> EFFECTIVE DATE - Flights departing at or after 00:01 EST (05:01 GMT) on  January 9, 2023
> EXPIRATION DATE - April 10, 2023
> CANCELS AND SUPERSEDES - EA 1546-21-02A

[TSA Emergency Amendment EA 1546-21-02B PDF](https://www.tsa.gov/sites/default/files/ea_1546-21-02b.pdf)