# US Vaccination Requirements end-date

Tags: usa, covid-19, vaccinations

This is a follow-up to my earlier question - [Vaccination requirement for entering the US](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/178646/vaccination-requirement-for-entering-the-us).  I have read that the Covid public health emergency is (mostly) officially over in the US, while some restrictions remain until May 11. However, in my reading online recently I still haven't been able to determine whether the vaccination requirement for foreigners arriving in the US by air will also be removed on May 11.

This [CBS News article](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/covid-vaccination-rule-international-travelers/) says:

> The Transportation Security Administration last moved to renew the
> rule earlier this month only through May 11, the same day as the
> public health emergency is due to end.
>
> The White House first ordered the requirement in October 2021. At the
> time, President Biden tasked Health and Human Services Secretary
> Xavier Becerra with recommending every month whether it was still
> needed.
>
> Asked whether Becerra has decided to end the rule, a spokesperson for
> the Department of Health and Human Services said **there was no update
> to share on the future of the requirement.**

(bolding added by me)

Additionally the [CDC "Proof of Vaccination" page](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/proof-of-vaccination.html) still says vaccination is required and also hasn't been updated to indicate a (possible) end-date for this requirement.  The CDC page was last updated on April 27, 2023, so it's not like it's just the original info.

> Noncitizens who are nonimmigrants and seeking to enter the United
> States by air are required to show proof of being fully vaccinated
> against COVID-19 before boarding a flight to the United States from a
> foreign country.
>
> If you are not fully vaccinated against COVID-19, you will NOT be
> allowed to board a flight to the United States, unless you meet the
> criteria for an exception under the Proclamation and CDC’s Amended
> Order. A booster dose is not needed to meet this requirement.

And this [Reuters article](https://www.reuters.com/world/us/us-end-covid-19-vaccination-requirements-may-11-white-house-2023-05-01/) says that the vaccination requirement had been removed for land and ferry entry (but doesn't mention air travel).

> The Homeland Security Department also said Monday starting May 12 it
> will no longer require non-U.S. travelers entering the United States
> via land ports of entry and ferries to be vaccinated against COVID-19
> and provide proof of vaccination upon request.

**Has the vaccination requirement for foreigners entering the US by air also been removed (either now or at May 11)?**

Comment: if you're vaccinated, it doesn't matter. if you have a good reason for not being vaccinated, it also doesn't matter

Comment: @njzk2 Only if the US government accepts your reason for not being vaccinated and grants you an exception to enter. I am vaccinated, but still need the info.

Comment: "And this Reuters article says that the vaccination requirement had been removed for land and ferry entry, but not yet for air travel." No, your quote does not say that it had not been removed for air travel. It says that DHS removed the requirements for land and ferry entry, because the vaccination requirements for land and ferry entry were imposed by DHS regulations, not by the President, and therefore they are for DHS to remove. The vaccination requirements for air entry were imposed by Presidential proclamation, not by the DHS, and they are therefore not for the DHS to remove.

Comment: @user102008 Yes, sorry that was incorrectly worded in my question

Comment: note that not being a public health *emergency* doesn't mean that it's not a public health *massive problem* and it doesn't really mean anything about vaccination requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the White House, [all vaccination requirements](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/statements-releases/2023/05/01/the-biden-administration-will-end-covid-19-vaccination-requirements-for-federal-employees-contractors-international-travelers-head-start-educators-and-cms-certified-facilities/) should end on May 11th:

> Today, we are announcing that the Administration will end the COVID-19 vaccine requirements for Federal employees, Federal contractors, and **international air travelers** at the end of the day on May 11, the same day that the COVID-19 public health emergency ends. Additionally, HHS and DHS announced today that they will start the process to end their vaccination requirements for Head Start educators, CMS-certified healthcare facilities, and **certain noncitizens at the land border**.

Comment: Interesting. I guess we now wait and see what the details are. Thanks

Comment: @Midavalo Timatic says all rules are now fully abolished. The pandemic is completely and utterly over, with zero rules or precautions whatsoever left anywhere :-)